# Adding A CSRF token to a post request in Angular js

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, spring-security, http-headers, http-error

I am using Angularjs with Spring Security. When I send a registration form off to the server I get the 403 forbidden error.  I have added the

```
.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository());
```

Configuratiion to my configure(HttpSecurity http) method.

I have added the

```
$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;

$httpProvider.interceptors.push('XSRFInterceptor');
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

To the config method of my angular module.

I have tried to follow the Spring Angular tutorials but it is not working for me.

**Spring Security Settings**

```
@Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{

    http
    .httpBasic().and()
      .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/todos").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
      .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .usernameParameter("email")
        .passwordParameter("password")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
      .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository());
  }
  private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
      HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
      repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
      return repository;
    }


public class CsrfHeaderFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
      HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
          CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class
            .getName());
          if (csrf != null) {
              Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
              String token = csrf.getToken();
              if (cookie==null || token!=null && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
                cookie.setPath("/");
                response.addCookie(cookie);
              }
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
  }
```

**Angularjs**

```
var todoApp = angular.module('todoApp', [
    'ngCookies',
    'ui.router',
    'jcs-autoValidate',
    'angular-ladda'
]);

todoApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {


$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('XSRFInterceptor');

$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
});
```

**User Service**

```
create: function(userData, callback) {
        $http.post('/api/users', userData).then(function (res) {
                return callback(res.data); 
            }, 'error')
        },
```

**I added this factory to my project, and it is taken from this question: [HTTP Status 403 - Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31978464/http-status-403-invalid-csrf-token-null-was-found-on-the-request-parameter)**

```
todoApp.factory('XSRFInterceptor', function ($cookies, $log) {

    var XSRFInterceptor = {

      request: function(config) {

        var token = $cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN');

        if (token) {
          config.headers['X-XSRF-TOKEN'] = token;
          $log.info("X-XSRF-TOKEN: " + token);
        }

        return config;
      }
    };
    return XSRFInterceptor;
  });
```

My understanding of this code, was that it adds the CSRF token to the header. But this did not turn out to be true. Any help would be great.